# HDF5 Cpp - retrieving the names of all groups in a file

Tags: c++, hdf5

I try to read and save the names of all groups in a file (in die root-group of the file).
So I use `H5Literate` to iterate over all objects in the root-group.

My problem is, that I can print the names of the groups but I don't know how I can save them in an array.

My operator function looks like this:

```
extern "C" herr_t file_info(hid_t loc_id, int *mom, string *Moments, const char *name, const H5L_info_t *linfo,
void *opdata);
{
hid_t group;

group = H5Gopen2(loc_id, name, H5P_DEFAULT);

cout << "Name : " << name << endl;
Moments[mom]=name;
H5Gclose(group);
mom++;
return 0;
}
```

the Iteration looks as follows:

```
Group *rootGr = new Group (file->openGroup("/"));
    hsize_t numMom = rootGr->getNumObjs();

    string Moments[numMom];
    int mom=0;

    herr_t idx = H5Literate(rootGr->getId(), H5_INDEX_NAME, H5_ITER_INC, NULL, file_info, NULL);
```

The `cout` works but I get an error when trying to save the name in `Moments[mom]`.

What is wrong here?

EDIT: Errors are:

```
invalid conversion from 'herr_t (*)(hid_t, int*, std::string*, const char*, const H5L_info_t*, void*) {aka int (*)(int, int*, std::basic_string<char>*, const char*, const H5L_info_t*, void*)}' to 'H5L_iterate_t {aka int (*)(int, const char*, const H5L_info_t*, void*)}' [-fpermissive]    C/C++ Problem

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int H5Literate(int, enum H5_index_t, enum {H5public.h:9387}, unsigned long long int *, int (*)(int, const char *, const {H5Lpublic.h:3236} *, void *), void *)
    Semantic Error

invalid types 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}[int*]' for array subscript   C/C++ Problem

  initializing argument 5 of 'herr_t H5Literate(hid_t, H5_index_t, H5_iter_order_t, hsize_t*, H5L_iterate_t, void*)' [-fpermissive] C/C++ Problem
```

EDIT 2:

I fixed it:

I added a global

```
std::vector<string> GroupNames;
```

then my operator function lookes like this:

```
herr_t
file_info(hid_t loc_id, const char *name, const H5L_info_t *linfo, void *opdata)
{
hid_t group;

group = H5Gopen2(loc_id, name, H5P_DEFAULT);

GroupNames.push_back(name);
cout << "Name : " << name << endl;
H5Gclose(group);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I have added it to the Question. See edits (:

Comment: Okay, good :). Glad it worked out

Answer (score 1):

Even though a global variable "works", you should pass your data through the void pointer.

```
herr_t
file_info(hid_t loc_id, const char *name, const H5L_info_t *linfo, void *opdata)
    {
    hid_t group;
    auto group_names=reinterpret_cast< std::vector<std::string>* >(opdata);
    group = H5Gopen2(loc_id, name, H5P_DEFAULT);
    //do stuff with group object, if needed
    group_names->push_back(name);
    cout << "Name : " << name << endl;
    H5Gclose(group);
    return 0;
    }
```

The new call becomes

```
 std::vector<std::string> group_names;
 herr_t idx = H5Literate(rootGr->getId(), H5_INDEX_NAME, H5_ITER_INC, NULL, file_info, &group_names);
```

Extra exercise: What happens if group_names->push_back(name) throws?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to `H5Gopen2()` and `H5Gclose()` if all you're doing is pushing back names that are already in the parameters?

Comment: You do not need to open the group. In my code, I needed to list the content of the group. The main point is that you should pass a pointer to the extra data.

Comment: OK. Got it. Fixed your code with a comment. Hope that's OK :)

Comment: It is fine. But as said in the answer, there should be RAII managment for the group handle, and there has to be a try block around the whole thing because the library does not expect an exception to leave the callback.